# Wordpress > settings > media > large image size not working

Tags: wordpress, image-size

In my newest wordpress website, I found something weird for the first time.

After setting up the new website and adding couple of pages, I decided to have the largest image larger.

Admin > Settings > Medias then change large image size to a bigger one ; 900 x 900 px > save

Went to upload new images (large ones over 1200 px) but once they are uploaded, it shows me that the largest size is around 625 px

PS I use WP Twenty Twelve theme

Answer (score 1):

Revv,

Look in your functions.php file for the following: set_post_thumbnail_size

You should be able to change the numbers that follow that string to match your needs.

Comment: **Heres is what i found in TwentyTwelve functions.php file**

 ` // Set up the content width value based on the theme's design and  stylesheet.
if ( ! isset( $content_width ) )
 $content_width = 625; `

  ` //* @uses set_post_thumbnail_size() To set a custom post thumbnail size. `

  ` // This theme uses a custom image size for featured images, displayed on "standard" posts.
 add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
 set_post_thumbnail_size( 624, 9999 ); // Unlimited height, soft crop `

Comment: Change the 624 in set_post_thumbnail_size( 624, 9999 ) to a larger size and see if that changes it. Let me know.

Comment: Thanks. Any way to do it without playing with function file ? Possible ? And just to understand, it is what's fault doing this bug exacly ?

Comment: I guess you could change the CSS for the img property to 100%. Not how that will play into the rest of your site, though.

Comment: No, won't work since WP have my Large cropped image smaller, so it will do pixelisation images, not so pretty, lol.